# Closed question notification should have a link to the close vote

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

When you find a question which has been closed, this is the information you are presented with (for example):

[image: Closed question]

As you can see, the only links present are those for the users who closed the question, the help center explanation of what closed means and links to comment or edit the question.

From what I can see, the only way to navigate from this block to the actual closed vote is to pick whichever user is the least active from the list, go onto their review activity and see if you can locate their close vote, which is a real pain if its an old question or highly active set of users.

Can you please add a link to the close vote, perhaps on the date bit, so it would say:

> **closed** as primarily opinion-based by GµårÐïåñ, KeyBrd Basher, Meat Trademark, Liath, Shevliaskovic [**Jun 27 at 16:33**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/close/11866)

So you don't have to go down this long and winding path to find it?

Comment: So you want a link to the *review item*? Not all questions are closed through review though. And what exactly would you need to get to that for? It's not relevant in the majority of (if not all) cases.

Comment: @animuson That's right, in this particular case I wanted to try and see if there was an intersection of the 4 people who voted to close it and the 4 people who are currently voting to reopen it.

Comment: I'm not sure what actual *"vote"* it is you want to see, the review item? What would be gained from that? What would indeed be a good idea was if the close-message would list all the individual reason instead of just the majority vote, since sometimes an individual vote was taken for a different reason and this is important information for the asker and anyone else. But I'm not sure this is what you're actually asking here.